# GWT: How to distinguish ClickEvent on anchor in HTML component?

Tags: gwt, event-handling, onclick, anchor

I have com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML component which contains some anchors.
When the component is clicked I need distinguish the clicks on anchors from the clicks on rest of the content of the component.

Example:

```
htmlText = new HTML();
htmlText.setHTML("foo <a href=http://stackoverflow.com target=_blank>stackoverflow</a> bar");
htmlText.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        if (!anchorClicked(event)) doSomethingElse();
    }
});
```

When the "stackoverflow" hyperlink is clicked, I want default behaviour - go to stackoverflow.com. When "foo" or "bar" is clicked, I want "doSomethingElse()" to be called.
Is there anyway to achieve that? What should be in the anchorClicked(e) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to check if your EventTarget is the hyperlink element (or a child of hyperlink).

Lets say the id of your hyperlink is "corvus-link"

```
Element link = Document.get().getElementById("corvus-link");
Element trgt = Element.as(e.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
```

Then what you need to check in your case is:

`link.isOrHasChild(trgt);`

EDIT:

the method you've asked for would look something like this:

```
boolean anchorClicked(e) 
{
    Element link = Document.get().getElementById("corvus-link");
    Element trgt = Element.as(e.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());

    return link.isOrHasChild(trgt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solution I used. It's based on idea provided by @Amey. I had to modify his solution, because my HTML component may contain multiple anchors.

```
htmlText = new HTML();
htmlText.getElement().setId("HtmlTextArea");
```

...

```
private boolean anchorClicked(ClickEvent event) {
    NodeList<Element> links = Document.get().getElementById("HtmlTextArea").getElementsByTagName("a");
    Element target = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());

    for (int i = 0; i < links.getLength(); i++) {
        if (links.getItem(i).isOrHasChild(target)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```